# Why is the noun "brush-off" hyphenated when the verb "to brush off" is not?

Tags: verbs, nouns, hyphenation

I'd like to know the reason for the punctuation of the noun "brush-off" and the verb "to brush off": they have related meanings, but "brush-off" is the result of "to brush off", essentially. But one cannot write "to brush-off" as that just looks weird, as it is used for the noun version.

So the question, is the hyphen often used like this in English to differentiate a derived noun from a verb?

Comment: Yes, it does. One can receive a *brush-off* when requesting a *turn-down* service at an *up-market* hotel near the *turn-off*. One might even feel *put-off* by the experience.

Comment: I don't think there is a verb "up-market".

Comment: Related: [“Sign in”, “signin” or “sign-in”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49850), [Topup vs top-up](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177657)

Comment: This is about nouns from phrasal verbs, not verbs from noun phrases, where the hyphenation scheme is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The punctuation mark you're talking about is a hyphen, not a dash, but either would be out of place in phrasal verbs like *brush off*, where in some meanings, the phrase will divide:

> Sarah can't stand Mark, so she *brushed* him *off* at the party.

The noun derived from this verb is written with a hyphen: [brush-off](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brush--off?s=t), but often a word may become so entrenched in the language that the hyphen disappears and the two elements are joined into one compound word. *Callback*, for instance, is [rapidly overtaking](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=callback%2Ccall-back&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccallback%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccall%20-%20back%3B%2Cc0) the hyphenated form *call-back.*

Comment: Sorry, hyphen. In programming I only hear "dash". Also in programming I only ever saw "callback". Unless it's "call me back" or something like that. Is there a rule about this usage of the hyphen?

Comment: The general preference is for the use of a hyphen, but as I've explained, it's a dynamic process where some words move toward a compound without one. People have been giving each other the _brush-off_ since the 1950s, so chances are good the hyphen is here to stay. You can always check a dictionary in each case, or, as with learning any language, copy the usage of those you want or need to impress.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/435328/two-word-verbs-described-with-one-word-nouns/498895#498895  Also, in programming the hyphen probably doesn't show up because most languages don't allow hyphens inside identifiers or keywords (to avoid conflict with subtraction).