# Two-word verbs described with One-word nouns

Tags: verbs, nouns, prepositions, compounds, language-evolution

I've noticed that certain (compound?) verbs are combined into one word when the process is used as a noun. It seems to generally be processes with a preposition in them. If the noun isn't combined into one word, it's usually at least hyphenated, which seems to be a pretty standard English word progression (two words, hyphen, one word).

Is there a name for this phenomenon? Do we know why it happens? Do the verbs stay separate or will they eventually combine like the nouns?

Examples:

- I **log in** using the **login** form.
- You can **make up** for the missed test with the **makeup** quiz.
- From this **lookout** tower, you can **look out** for miles.

Comment: base on the example sentences they are not compound words at all. they're just merely single words in a sentence.

Comment: Related: [Why is the noun “brush-off” hyphenated when the verb “to brush off” is not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425334)

Comment: @ArchieAzares Compound words are single words, and the words in the sentences provided are compound.

Comment: I log in/out? using that form.

Comment: @as4s4hetic one was single and the other was compound

Comment: If you have the knowhow, you know how to do it.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, read the how-to.

Comment: @as4s4hetic Phrasal verbs (verb+preposition) -- note the description "phrasal".

Comment: Books might be written but broadly, verbs are like nouns. “Lamp posts" became "lamp-posts" and now the main reason they're not "lamp(p)osts" is that either version would be awkward.

You can “make up” for much but whether with a “makeup” test is, to me, a style choice with no rules.

“Login” is a term used by people with no interest in language. Otherwise, they’d use either “log in” our “log-in”

Similarly, consider all the possible variations of “on air” or “in car”. Make up your own mind which to use, but either be prepared to explain it, or admit that to you it doesn’t much matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different cases: phrasal verbs and prepositional verbs, which can be a bit subtle to tell apart.

With phrasal verbs, a direct object can come between the verb and preposition:

```
I took the ladder down.
```

With prepositional verbs, a direct object cannot come between:

```
*I came the ladder down.
```

If the direct object is a pronoun, it *must* go between:

```
I took it down.
*I took down it.
```

This separability is probably why the phrasal verbs typically stayed spaced (although closing up the verb+preposition is certainly seen, many would consider it an error).

However, some phrasal and prepositional verbs have related nouns: There is such a thing as a "comedown" (a disappointment), and a "takedown" (in wrestling). As nouns, those are no longer a verb plus a preposition, and they get closed up (no space, or sometimes a hyphen).

Comment: I think I would say phrasal verbs versus verbs with a prepositional phrase: I came **down the ladder**. But besides semantics, I agree.